# Android 10: how to get write permissions on external USB drives

Tags: android-10, file-permissions

I've just bought a TvBox with Android 10 in it, and i've soon discovered that no app can write on the external HDD/flashdrives i attach to the USB port (seen as */storage/<long_number_here>* ).

This is a problem 'cause the internal storage of the TvBox isn't enough for the apps i want to use (KODI is a good example: it generate a lot of thumbnails, taking up much space, but i can't configure it to use the HDD folder 'cause it can't write to it) or 'cause i'd like to use a wifi connection to update the files in the HD (the file manager which provide the connection cannot do anything on the HD).

While i'm not an android/linux expert, i'm not afraid on using ADB, rooting the device if necessary, etc, so i'm asking what should i do to obtain writing permission on every external device i may plug in the USB port.

Comment: https://gettechsupport.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Force-allow-apps-to-write-in-external-storage.jpg.webp

Comment: Sadly, i don't have any of that options in my developer options.
I have one that says (translating from italian to english, sorry) "do not keep activities (delete any activity once interrupted by the user)" and "Force autorisation on external memory (allow the installation of whatever app on the external memory, no matter manifest values).

Comment: ***"Force autorisation on external memory** (allow the installation of whatever app on the external memory, no matter manifest values)"*

Comment: @alecxs, This does not work. File manager still can't write on external disk.

Comment: What file systems are on the external media you're trying to use?

Comment: @ChanganAuto: tried both NTFS and FAT32. The device creates automatically an Android and a Media folder on everythng plugged in it (the Media one is to record DTV on it), so the problem is really just on permissions, not on incompatibility of some sort.

Comment: stupid file manager? OTG usb-storage is provided only by uri not by path https://i.stack.imgur.com/a37p1.jpg

Comment: @alecxs: NO APP can write on the external drive(s), not just the file explorer (which is Xplore). Even the internal file manager.
I've never seen that dialog in this TvBox (even with my trusty old version of ES File Explorer, which i use from years on every cell i own): i was expecting it, but it never appeared.
Seems that i fall in the case mentioned here: https://www.lonelycatgames.com/docs/xplore/known-problems/write-external-storage
I have no "files" app (as mentioned in the "Why writing doesn’t work" chapter).

Comment: I don't have *com.android.documentsui*, too (at least not under that pkgname) https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDEqw.jpg